# How to properly define a windows foldername to be used with python?

Tags: python, windows, encoding

I have the following small code snippet in python 3.10 on windows 10 powershell

```
win_folder = b"C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin"
os.chdir(win_folder)
```

but when running this code I always get an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: b'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\STMicroelectronics\\STM32Cube\\STM32CubeProgrammer\x08in'
```

I also tried unicode string, byte string, with and without escaping the slash in "\b" and also the spaces:

```
win_folder = "C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\\bin"
```

But still no success.
Is there a way to automatically convert the string

```
myfolder = "C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin"
```

into a valid filename to be used within python? Or a way to define it properly?

Comment: Sounds like a typo. Backslashes  have to be escaped in literal strings. You have probably forgotten one so Python has converted the `\b` into a backspace with a `0x08` code...

Comment: You can also try using a raw string `r"C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin"`

Comment: Maybe the raw string seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first this is this is a byte string if you see b in the beginning of string you can decoded it to string

and also you can use format string in path like

path = r"c:/path-to-every-where"

'r in this case mean raw text

or better way is use a library for this like pathlib or os it self

in os lib you can use path like:

```
import os
os.path.join("C:\\", "Program\ Files\ (x86)\ ,","STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer","bin")

In [9]: os.path.join("C:\\", "Program\ Files\ (x86)\ ","STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer","bin")
Out[9]: 'C:\\Program\\ Files\\ (x86)\\ \\STMicroelectronics\\STM32Cube\\STM32CubeProgrammer\\bin'
```

or

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("c://path-to-every-where")

In [7]: pathlib.Path(os.getcwd())
Out[7]: WindowsPath('C:/Users/netadmin')
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried writing it like this

```
win_folder = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\STMicroelectronics\\STM32Cube\\STM32CubeProgrammer\\bin"
```

or this

```
win_folder = "C:/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin"
```

Comment: Nope. In Windows, a [path component separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) is _always_ ```\``` (U+005C,  *Reverse Solidus*) while `/` (U+002F,  *Solidus*) is a _reserved_ character. Use ```r"C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin"```.

Comment: Both works actually